# How to include HTML instead of a blade template for a Laravel Mailable?

Tags: php, laravel

For a Mailable, when using the ->view() method, instead of providing a Blade Template, like this

```
return $this->subject($this->subject)
                        ->view('mybladetemplate');
```

I would like to provide the HTML inline. For example

```
return $this->subject($this->subject)
                    ->view('<!DOCTYPE html... etc ');
```

Is this possible? Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: `$this->subject($this->subject)->view('html');` and on `html.blade.php` put your html content there

Comment: @EsTeAa thanks, but this is exactly what I don not want. It's very clear in the question.

Comment: If you want to return inline html, then you can do like this way : `return '<!DOCTYPE html... etc ';`

Comment: you can use the html method provided by `Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;`, `return $this->html($html)`